# Using Dictionary in Attribute Class

Tags: c#, attributes

I am trying to implement an `Attribute` class in which I also need to pass the `Dictionary<string, object>` in it.

When trying to do the same it is throwing an error

> ABC.cs(8366,6): error CS0181: Attribute constructor parameter 'Settings' has type 'Dictionary<string, object>', which is not a valid attribute parameter type.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All)]
public class TestAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string cName{ get; private set; }
    public string oName { get; private set; }
    public string aUser { get; private set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Settings { get; private set; }

    public TestAttribute(string cName, string oName, string aUser = null
        Dictionary<string, object> Settings = null)
    {
        this.cName= cName;
        this.oName= oName;
        this.aUser = aUser ;
        this.Settings = Settings ;
    }
}
```

I did some searching and found that attribute classes use primitive data types.
So, I wanted to know is there any way to add the Dictionary to the above class?

Comment: All the parameters that you pass to the attribute have to be available at compile time. `object` << might not be available.

Comment: @PeterCsala : As suggested, I modified it from `object` to `string` still I am getting the same error
ABC.cs(132,6): error CS0181: Attribute constructor parameter 'Settings' has type 'Dictionary<string, string>', which is not a valid attribute parameter type

Comment: Apologize I copy-pasted a wrong word. I wanted to emphasize that the dictionary can't be populated at compile-time. So, you could not have a property like that.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30045), you can only use certain types in an attribute:

> Change the data type of the parameter to `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Single`, `Double`, `Char`, `String`, `Boolean`, `System.Type`, or an enumeration type.

So no, you cannot use a `Dictionary` at all.

Having a bit more of a think about this. Since you called the property "Settings", that suggests the value should come from a config file anyway, so perhaps that should be taken into account. Another alternative would be to use an array of strings as key/value pairs and parse them out. For example:

```
public TestAttribute(string cName, string oName, string aUser = null,
    params string[] Settings) // use params to make it easier to specify values
{
    //snip

    // This is just an example and should include error checking etc.
    this.Settings = Settings
        .Select(s => s.Split('='))
        .ToDictionary(s => s[0], s=> s[1]);     
}
```

And now use it like this:

```
[Test("cname", "oname", "auser", "Setting1=Foo", "Setting2=Bar")]
public class Foo
{
    
}
```